# Could not import site.views. Error was: No module named views

Tags: python

DIRS

**./ksp**

```
__init__.py
jquery.pngFix.js
manage.py
passenger_wsgi.py
settings.py
site/
site_media/
templates/
tmp/
urls.py
```

**./ksp/site**

```
__init__.py
models.py
models_.py
myforms.py
urls.py
views.py
views_back.py
```

FILES

**./ksp/passenger_wsgi.py:**

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django-1.3')
sys.path.append('/home/p/pravicom/ksp/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**./ksp/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('', include('site.urls')),
)
```

**./ksp/site/urls.py:**

```
import views
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'views.ShowMain'),
#....
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

**./ksp/site/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from models import *
from myforms import *
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpRequest
from django import forms
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
import os, urlparse, Image, sys
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage


def custom_proc(request):
    return{
        'user': request.user
    }

def ShowMain(request):
    all_posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    return render_to_response("index.html", {'all_posts':all_posts}, context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=[custom_proc]))
```

**./ksp/settings.py:**

```
...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
#    'django.contrib.sites',
#    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'site',
)
...
```

Result:

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist
Exception Value:
Could not import site.views. Error was: No module named views

Comment: Can you show us the contents of ksp/site/views.py?

Comment: I did this with the login module. Below fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`site` was a poor name to call your module as collides with Python's `site` module.  You should rename it to something else that doesn't collide.  You might also get this to work by prepending your path to `sys.path`:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django-1.3')
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/p/pravicom/ksp/')
```

However, that's hackish at best, and may come to bite you in other ways down the road.  The best answer is to rename your package.

Comment: Ok - "mysite". Result: Could not import views. Error was: No module named views

Comment: After your `sys.path` is setup, do an `import mysite`, followed by a `print mysite.__file__`.  Make sure that the right file is being picked up.  Also, it looks like your urls is doing an `import views`.  That should probably be `from . import views`, or just `import mysite.views`.  You can't just do `import views` because `mysite` is not on your `sys.path`.  And `import views` will do an absolute import rather than a relative one.  IIRC, absolute imports are now the default in Python 2.7.

Comment: If that still doesn't fix the problem, then please update your question to include the full traceback.